# Sharing Linux Printer to windows

Tags: linux, windows, file-sharing

I want to share the printer connected to Linux with Windows machine, so that windows-user can print to this Linux printer.

How can I do this ?

P.S. I followed the http://tldp.org/HOWTO/SMB-HOWTO-9.html, but it did not worked.

I am using LFS-6.0 and windows machine is XP.

Comment: What didn't work? You didn't see the printer, you add the printer, or print on it? Did you restart samba after changing configuration? Do you have the printer configured in CUPS?

Answer (score 3):

Although I share the printers using Samba, I access them directly using CUPS.  Windows works well with the IPP protocol.  For postscript output I am using the MS Publisher Imagesetter driver.

If you are having problems with printer sharing using Samba, it may be a browsing issue.  You need to be able to see your server first.  From my wireless network I can't browse the printers on my server, although I have access to a share from the server.  They do show up if I choose `Select a shared printer by name`. (\servername) brings up a drop-down list.

Answer (score 0):

[Bonjour Printing Services](https://support.apple.com/kb/dl999?locale=en_GB) allows Windows to easily connect to Unix printers shared in the local network, even when those use dynamic IPs.

Potential missing drivers can be found at [nodevice.com](https://www.nodevice.com/).